# What logging system to use for methods in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, webforms

There is a webforms application with classes that contain lot of methods. I want to keep logs of the methods that are being called in a flexible and easy way.
I want to know which method has finally been called and some other additional info like:

- input values and
- result values
- Crash exceptions (if there is a crash)

Currently, I am using **log4net** for filesystem logging like:

```
using log4net;
private static readonly ILog Log1 = LogManager.GetLogger("Log1");

public int DoSomething(int itemId = 0)
{
    Log1.DebugFormat("[DoSomething] - Doing Something on item {0} Started", itemId );

    try
    {
        //something..
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log1.Debug("[DoSomething] - Something Failed", ex);
    }

    Log1.DebugFormat("[DoSomething] - Doing Something on item {0} Finished", itemId );

    return 0;
}
```

How is it possible to achieve this without writing every time these pieces of code in every method? Is there a better and automatic way?
What about the performance cost in every case?

An alternative approach would be great!

Comment: Common way to solve this is to use AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming). One example of implementation of this paradigm is PostSharp (https://www.postsharp.net/), but there are others.

Comment: It seems an approach.Have you ever used postsharp @Evk?

Comment: Yes, I use it all the time (I have paid version, but free version should be enough to achieve what you want).

Comment: @Evk what about performance ? is this something that I have to consider?

Comment: It rewrites your code (literally - after compilation it takes your assembly and injects\rewrites code inside it), so usually perfomance is not an issue - it will be about the same as you wrote that yourself.

Comment: I can write you a sample code with free version, so you can check yourself (code which they now provide for logging uses their paid diagnostics module).

Comment: @Evk I am waiting for the sample and thanks

Comment: You can also use Unity.WebForms. But here is a bit of a learning curve. And you can do it with interception without using attributes at all.
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx).
In addition download the nuget package Unity.WebForms for DI for Pages and UserControls.You are free to choose which logging framework you like. EntLib also has a Logging Application Block, but u can use Log4Net or what ever. For interception I would use Interfaces.As I said there is a bit of a learning curve here. But at the end you have Logging using interception in one place

Answer (score 1):

Below code should give you a starting point. It's a sample which uses console instead of log4net, but I think it's trivial to extend it to use whatever you need.

First install PostSharp nuget package. Then define new aspect:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class TraceAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{        
    private readonly string _argumentsFormat;        
    [NonSerialized]
    private string _methodName;        

    public TraceAttribute() {

    }

    public TraceAttribute(string argumentsFormat) {
        _argumentsFormat = argumentsFormat;
    }

    public override void RuntimeInitialize(MethodBase method) {
        _methodName = method.Name;
    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
        string msg = $"[{_methodName}]: entered";
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_argumentsFormat)) {
            msg += String.Format(". Arguments:" + _argumentsFormat, args.Arguments.ToArray());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    // Invoked at runtime after the target method is invoked (in a finally block).
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
        string msg = $"[{_methodName}]: exited";
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_argumentsFormat)) {
            msg += String.Format(". Arguments: " + _argumentsFormat, args.Arguments.ToArray());                
        }
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args) {
        string msg = $"[{_methodName}]: exception";
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_argumentsFormat))
        {
            msg += String.Format(". Arguments: " + _argumentsFormat, args.Arguments.ToArray());                
        }
        msg += ". Details: " + args.Exception.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```

What we basically do here is inheriting MethodBoundaryAspect and define what code should be executed when target method is entered, exited, and when exception is thrown. Use it like this:

```
public class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TestStuff(1);
        TestStuff(2);
        TestStuff(3);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [Trace("itemId: {0}")]
    static void TestStuff(int itemId) {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside TestStuff: " + itemId);
        if (itemId == 3)
            throw new Exception("Test exception");
    }
}
```

You can also apply that attribute to whole classes. In this case - all methods inside that class will be traced.

Comment: I'll give it a try @Evk and I'll come back